# List of attacks that try to trick browser to not use SOCKS/Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, attacks, information-leaks

I've heard it called "disbanding" attacks where the attacker induces a client into not routing a connection over Tor. Basically all of the things that the TBB protects against.

Examples might be leaking DNS because it's using SOCKS4 or using WebRTC to discover the private IP of the user.

Is there an existing list of all such attacks, or can you make a list off to top of your head?

Comment: I have been searching for more information on this for days and tonight I found something you might find useful. https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#proxy-obedience You mentioned DNS leaks and WebRTC, the link seems to provide a fairly comprehensive list of what the tor developers have done with Tor Browser to prevent this type of attack from being successful. Is this something like what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

adding to the types you've mentioned there're two other kinds of them:

- **Zero-Day exploits** Tor browser is a Firefox by roots, so some Firefox zero-day exploits are affecting it too. It's OK for *any* software to have mistakes - it's written by people, people do mistakes.
- **External container** Using things that are inside the browser is safe in case of Tor browser or other ones - they will use proxies configured. However calling some external components like Adobe Flash will cause a separated execution container being created *by OS* - and it can just ignore the proxy settings and try to make a direct request and leak data.